# Передача параметров в функцию JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, frontend

Друзья, всем привет!
Изучаю JS, возник следующий вопрос:

почему в результате выполнения следующего кода, массив arr не заквадратится?
вроде ж по ссылке передаются аргументы...
Всем спасибо за помощь)

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function test(arr) {
   arr = arr.map((item) => {
      return item * item;
   });
}

test(arr);
```

Comment: Передаются по ссылке. Но вы не меняете исходный массив, а создаёте новый и  заменяете ссылку

Comment: То есть изменить ссылку, выходит, нельзя?

Comment: Нельзя. Зачем её менять?

Comment: Ну не знаю, можно и без этого конечно обойтись...
Просто как то так привык ещё с плюсов - например если необходимо вернуть несколько значений из функции. Передал по ссылке несколько параметров и готово)

Comment: Ну так и тут так же. Передал массив. Функция изменила значения *внутри* массива. Если вам так будет проще, то можно считать что в JS параметры функции всегда передаются по значению. Просто для непримитивных объектов этим значением является ссылка на объект.

Comment: И помните что в JS нет оператора `&` для взятия адреса, так что как только у вас возникнет желание передать параметр по ссылке, вспомните что получить ссылку вы не сможете и желание сразу пропадёт =)

Comment: Да, спасибо большое за совет) 
Пока такого, слава богу, ещё не возникало..)

Answer (score 3):

Глобальная переменная и параметр функции имеют одинаковые имена, и поэтому функция работает с локальной переменной. Просто дайте аргументу другое имя:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function test(bbb) {
  arr = bbb.map((item) => {
    return item * item;
  });
}

test(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!)

Comment: @Константин: сам недавно освежал в памяти, но потерял ссылку, где было ооочень понятно разжёвано.

Comment: Аргументы функции получают не ссылку а копию самого объекта. А дальше вы работаете копией

Answer (score 2):

Нужно из функции что-то вернуть через `return`

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function test(arr) {
   return arr.map((item) => {
      return item * item;
   });
}

console.log(test(arr));
```

Или я не так понял вопрос?)

Comment: Да, я согласен с Вами, такое же решение пришло и мне)
Просто интересна сама логика работы, тип массив по идее в JS по ссылке передаётся, а раз по ссылке, то мой код должен сработать)

Comment: @Константин, нет не должен, так как ты меняешь саму ссылку, а не объект по ссылке.

Comment: @Grundy, зачем тогда нужна ссылка, если нельзя поменять данные на которые она ссылается? В чем смысл передачи данных по ссылке тогда?

Comment: @Константин, данные поменять как раз можно. А ты хочешь чтобы поменялась сама ссылка

Comment: @Grundy, да, я понимаю о чём ты говоришь, согласен, я как раз пытаюсь поменять ссылку. Не знаешь - почему нельзя её поменять?

Comment: @Константин, потому что это не предусмотрено языком ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ вместо этого ты просто можешь изменить существующий объект, удалив ненужные и вставив новые. Например с помощью `.splice`

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо)